# ModelForm not saving data into the model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have looked at all similar questions but none of them seem to help.

This is my `POST` method inside `class ProfileEditView(generic.DetailView):`

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    profile_id = kwargs.get('pk')
    user_detail = User.objects.get(id=profile_id)

    form  = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_detail)
    if form.is_valid():
        updated = form.save(commit=False)
        updated.phone = form.cleaned_data["phone"]
        updated.address = form.cleaned_data["address"]
        updated.gender = form.cleaned_data["gender"]
        updated.save()
        messages.success(request, "Profile details updated.")
        return redirect("profileview", profile_id)
    else:
        context = {}
        context["form"] = form
        context["profile_id"] = kwargs["pk"]
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'profile_edit_view' profile_id %}">
{% csrf_token %}

{{form|crispy}}

<input type="submit" value="Save">

</form>
```

Models.py

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    profile_picture = models.FileField(upload_to=profile_image_upload, null=True, blank=True)

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices=gender_choices)
```

Comment: I don't get it, why do you manually take all the data from `form.cleaned_data` and manually save them? Why can't you just call `updated = form.save()`?

Comment: tried that too, still didn't work :(

Comment: @ShangWang Has 'instance' attribute in `form  = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_detail)` anything to do with this issue ?

Comment: What does happen when you submit the form? Is the form valid? What does `EditProfileForm` look like? It would probably be easier to use [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) instead of `DetailView`.

Comment: OK, `still didn't work` is not at all helpful. You need to tell me how exactly it doesn't work. Do you see errors? Have you checked the instance `updated` that's saved?

Comment: Yes, the form is valid, `form.cleaned_data` shows the updated values, but it's not being saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `EditProfileForm` is editing the `UserDetail`, then `instance` should be a `UserDetail` instance. You are currently passing the `user` instead. Try changing it to:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_id = kwargs.get('pk')
    user_detail = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    user_detail = user.userdetail

    form  = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user_detail)
```

Comment: thank you, i was messing around with `User` and 'UserDetail'. I had used `model = User`. Anyway, it's working now. :)